# Does a Magnetar have a magnetic event horizon different than it's schwarzchild radius?

Tags: gravity, magnetic-fields, event-horizon

Being the strongest magnets in the universe I think there would be a point of know return different for a neodymium magnets then that of similar non magnetic mass.

Comment: What kind of point of no return are you considering? Event horizons in GR are limits for all particles no matter their properties. But e.g. rotating black holes have a tendency to make objects rotating in the opposite direction plunge in more strongly than co-rotating objects, yet this is not a rotational event horizon.

Comment: I guess then I am asking about a magnetic point of no return.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by a "magnetic point of no return"? It is not a standard physics term.